# Find and Replace Regex in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, replace, dreamweaver

I want to find `[value-XXX]` and replace it with `?`.  The `XXX` is a number ranging from 1 to 661.  This means there are 661 `[value-XXX]`'s in my document.  I see there is a regular expression option in Dreamweaver, so how could I leverage that to find these?

Comment: What's a rejax? Is it a reqular experssion?

Comment: Will the `1`s be formatted like `001`, or `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `1`'s are following the format of `XXX` (`001`), you can use `\[value-([0-5]\d{2}|6[0-5]\d|66[01])\]`.  I did some testing using the regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/ZlhXfpK1lw).

This breaks down into three smaller regex combinations inside the larger `[value-XXX]` check.  This is seen in the `([0-5]\d{2}|6[0-5]\d|66[01])` part inside the `value` piece.  Three smaller regex are `or`ed together to solve the issue of 1 to 661.

1. `[0-5]\d{2}` - this covers all numbers starting with `0-5` and then followed by any two digits.  This checks for numbers `001-599`.
2. `6[0-5]\d` - this covers checking for a 6 followed by `0-5` and then any digit.  You have to catch `[0-5]` and then a digit specifically so you don't allow numbers like 662.  This covers `600-659`
3. `66[01]` - checks the last two cases, two 6 followed by a 1 or 2.  This covers `660-661`.

Comment: @DiliniWasana I wanted to get the quick answer in for you, I just edited the post with some explanation breaking down the different pieces.  It is a simple check for the `[value-]` part, and then a little more complex 3 part `OR` check for the conditions you set around numbers (1-661).

Comment: @DiliniWasana glad to help.  I like breaking down the regex answers for people.  Regex like this can seem really scary but when you break them down and attack them in smaller pieces they can be pretty quick to write up.